# Embed a wasm runtime into a standalone Rust app and allow wasm and host functions to call each other

Tags: rust, webassembly

Is it possible to write a standalone Rust app like the following, compile it into 2 parts, one wasm and one native , and embed a wasm runtime (like `wasmtime`) into the final binary and the whole piece just work like a single app?

WasmEdge has a macro `#[wasmedge_bindgen]` that marks a wasm func, but nothing that makes a host function accessible in wasm runtime though.

```
#[make_a_wasm_func]
fn f1(i: i32)->i32{
    i+1
}


#[make_a_host_func_that_can_be_called_from_wasm]
fn f2(i: i32)->i32{
    f1(i)+2
} 

#[make_a_wasm_func]
fn f3(i:i32)-> i32{
    f2(i)+3
}

fn main(){
    let r=f3(1);
    println!("{}",r);   

}

The expected output is 7.
```

Comment: I am looking at some thing very similar and my understanding is that "host" functions need to be imported into the "wasm" part as "import objects". I understand this is probably not the answer you are looking for but I thought that I might add a little more context.

Comment: `WasmEdge` published a series of examples in [this repo](https://github.com/second-state/wasmedge-rustsdk-examples). The examples in the recent release cover some basic use cases, such as how to call a wasm library from the host. For your use case, [Example 2](https://github.com/second-state/wasmedge-rustsdk-examples/tree/main/call-wasm-lib-from-host), [Example 2-1](https://github.com/second-state/wasmedge-rustsdk-examples/tree/main/call-wasm-lib-with-external-deps) and [Example 4](https://github.com/second-state/wasmedge-rustsdk-examples/tree/main/define-host-func) could help you.

Answer (score 2):

Maintainer of [WasmEdge](https://wasmedge.org/) here. Hope the following example code can help you:

```rust
use wasmedge_sdk::{
    error::HostFuncError, host_function, params, Caller, ImportObjectBuilder, ValType, Vm, WasmVal,
    WasmValue,
};

#[host_function]
fn my_add(_caller: Caller, input: Vec<WasmValue>) -> Result<Vec<WasmValue>, HostFuncError> {
    // check the number of inputs
    if input.len() != 2 {
        return Err(HostFuncError::User(1));
    }

    // parse the first input of WebAssembly value type into Rust built-in value type
    let a = if input[0].ty() == ValType::I32 {
        input[0].to_i32()
    } else {
        return Err(HostFuncError::User(2));
    };

    // parse the second input of WebAssembly value type into Rust built-in value type
    let b = if input[1].ty() == ValType::I32 {
        input[1].to_i32()
    } else {
        return Err(HostFuncError::User(3));
    };

    let c = a + b;

    Ok(vec![WasmValue::from_i32(c)])
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // create an import module
    let import = ImportObjectBuilder::new()
        .with_func::<(i32, i32), i32>("add", my_add)?
        .build("extern")?;

    // create a new vm with default config and register the import module into the vm.
    let res = Vm::new(None)?.register_import_module(import)?.run_func(
        Some("extern"),
        "add",
        params!(15, 51),
    )?;

    println!("add({}, {}) = {}", 15, 51, res[0].to_i32());

    Ok(())
}
```

In addition, add the following dependency in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
wasmedge-sdk = "0.7.1"
```